# Silverstripe save meta tags in html editor

Tags: silverstripe

I am working on Siverstripe 3.0 and everything is working fine. Now I got the requirement to save meta tag through html editor.
I have added the code this way:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOptions(array(
    "extended_valid_elements" => "meta[content|name]"
));
```

If I add a meta tag in the editor this way it works

```
<meta name="fdfdfdf" content="sdfdfdfdf"></meta>
```

But if I try to add meta tag this way it doesn't work

```
<meta name="fdfdfdf" content="sdfdfdfdf" />
```

How can I make that work?
Thank You.

Comment: Are you able to use a more recent version of SilverStripe? 3.x has its own field for meta tags, so you shouldn't need to add them to HTML content

Comment: According to https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_meta.asp meta tags always go inside the `<head>` element, therefore you shouldn't use Content's HTMLEditor for it but the seperate "Metadata" textarea which is normally below Content. Also <meta ... /> is valid (x)html, as it's an empty, self closing tag.